# How can I get my tabs to spread to the width of my window?

Tags: tabbed-user-interface

[image]

I can't see a number of the tabs at the top, even though there's space to show them all. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you reproduce this behavior when starting vim without a vimrc? (`vim -U NONE`) Because I can't reproduce the problem. If you can't reproduce the problem with `vim -U NONE` then it comes from your vimrc and [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) should help you to find the problematic setting.

Comment: Is this airline? It has similar problems and I haven't found yet time to fix it. Probably other plugins have the same problem. In any case, you can use your own custom tabline, see `:h setting-tabline` for an example.